# How do I initialize a java script dictionary ( similar to setdefault in python )

Tags: javascript

Is there a better way to initialize the dictionary below with an empty Array?

```
itemGroups = {}

if( ! (group  in itemGroups) ){
    itemGroups[ group ] = {}
}

if ( ! (itemStr in itemGroups[group])) {

    itemGroups[group][ itemStr ] = []
}

itemGroups[group][ itemStr ].push( item )
```

Answer (score 0):

While I generally don't like code abbreviations. The `||` operator can indeed be handy for this kind of tasks:

```
itemGroups = {}

itemGroups[group] = itemGroups[group] || {}
itemGroups[group][itemStr] = itemGroups[group][itemStr] || []


itemGroups[group][itemStr].push( item )
```

But if this is really better is up to your preference. And you need to keep in mind that `itemGroups[ group ] || {}` does not check if the `group` is present in `itemGroups` it only checks if the value hold is truthy or not, so it is technically not equal to your code.

Another thing you could do is to write a helper function:

```
function setIfNotExists(obj, key, value) {
  if( ! (key  in obj) ){
    obj[ key ] = value
  }
}

itemGroups = {}

setIfNotExists(itemGroups, group, {})
setIfNotExists(itemGroups[group], itemStr, [])

itemGroups[group][itemStr].push( item )
```

That would be equal to your code, and due to the function name, it expresses more what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a function for creating nested objects and for the last wanted property an array. Finally push the value to the array.

```js
const
    addItem = (target, path, value) => path
        .reduce((o, k, i, { length }) => o[k] = o[k] || (i + 1 === length ? [] : {}), target)
        .push(value);

var itemGroups = {},
    group = 'foo',
    itemStr = 'bar',
    item = 'baz';

addItem(itemGroups, [group, itemStr], item);

console.log(itemGroups);
```